$A$ and $B$ is compact space of normed vector space then $A+B$ is compact.
If $A$ and $B$ are compact subset of a normed vector space then $A+ B$ is also compact space, right?
Because since $A\times B$ is compact and $f:A\times B \rightarrow A+B$ such that $f(a,b) = a +b $ is continuous by sequentially criteria.
So a continuous image of compact space is compact.
There is a similar question on Mathstack exchange but it is generalize version of normed vector space.

Yes, image of a compact space by a continuous map is compact. What you said is correct.

I would prefer to say that $f \colon X \times X \to X$, $f(u,v)=u+v$, is continuous and $f(A \times B) = A+B$.

@TimonKolt This question has stronger condition. Can you edit the question ?

@Texas i dont know how you want me to edit your question, i think it is best if you edit it the way you want. To be honest i think think this question should be closed because it really is a duplicate and to become a non duplicate it would need  to become a totally new question.

@timonkolt okay thank you
